# Char * Bad Access Error

Tags: c, pointers, c-strings

I'm trying to grasp the idea of pointers but can't get the hang of it. Why does this code assign the correct value to `s`, but create a runtime error when I try to use it on `t`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    char *s;
    char *t;

    printf("s: ");
    scanf("%s", s);

    printf("t: ");
    scanf("%s", t);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You haven't allocated any memory

Comment: How would I correctly Allocate the memory? I have tried this. 
        char *s = malloc(20 *sizeof(char));
        char *t = malloc(20 * sizeof(char));

Comment: Please read a c book or tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

You have dynamically allocate memory for your char pointers, Otherwise it will not work. An uninitialized pointer has garbage.

```
//a macro to hold the size of the array.

#define DIM 12

char *s = malloc(sizeof(char) * DIM);
char *t = malloc(sizeof(char) * DIM);

printf("s: ");
scanf("%s", s);

printf("t: ");
scanf("%s", t);
```

Don't forget to free the memory from the heap when you are done with it.

```
free(t);
free(s);
```

If you don't want to allocate memory on the heap then you can use char arrays which you don't have to free after using it with `scanf`:

```
char t[DIM];
char s[DIM];
```

Comment: @MDXF thanks for the edit

Answer (score 1):

Which book are you reading? It seems strange that your book wouldn't teach you something like this...

The idea of pointers is that they allow functions such as `scanf` to assign to an object they point at (hence the name, *pointers* tend to *point at* things). Like other variables, however, *you need to initialise them*!

Suppose you have a function `add_one` which adds to its argument:

```
void add_one(int x) {
    x++;
}
```

This function is useless as the changes it makes to `x` aren't visible to the caller, due to a concept known as *pass-by-value* where *copies* of the values passed in are made, which end up being what gets modified (and so the *original* remains the same).

You need to make `x` a pointer to make that change visible outside of `add_one`, and the same change was necessary for `scanf`.

```
void add_one(int *x) {
    (*x)++; // equivalent to x[0]++;
}
```

Of course, this won't work if `x` doesn't actually point to something! In your example, you've got uninitialised pointer variables; they're pointing at... nothing? anything? who cares? **Make them point somewhere!**

You can do this by:

- Using the `&`address-of operator on a variable. For example:

  ```
  int x;
  int *pointer_to_x = &x;
  ```
- Declaring an array, and using the identifier of the array, possibly in conjunction with the `+` addition operator to point at an element in the array. For example:

  ```
  int array[42];
  int *pointer_to_first = array + 0;
  int *pointer_to_second = array + 1;
  ```
- Calling `malloc`, `realloc`, `calloc` or some other function that returns a pointer to a suitably sized object. For example:

  ```
  int *pointer_to_whatever = malloc(sizeof *pointer_to_whatever);
  // Remember to free(pointer_to_whatever) ONCE when you're done with it
  ```